# CUDA allocating array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation

Whenever I run my script that contains those lines:

```
   char ** gpu_reads;
   HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_reads, inputDim * sizeof(char *)));
   for(i=0; i<inputDim; i++) {
      HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&(gpu_reads[i]), (READS_LENGTH + 1) * sizeof(char)));
   }
   for(i=0; i<inputDim; i++) {
      HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(gpu_reads[i], reads[i], sizeof(char) * (READS_LENGTH + 1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
   }
```

The second line returns an "unknown error". I tried different allocation in my program (this was the first one) but none of them worked.

The purpose of those lines is simply allocating an array (of length fixed by user, using the variable `inputDim` of strings (of fixed length).

I tried different version (i.e. using only 3 pointers, 1 pointer...) but none seems to work...

Any ideas?

The full code is available at my GitHub [repository](https://github.com/Cordaz/AAPPproject/blob/master/cuda_main.cu), where many allocation are made.

Comment: Why do have the same number of stars on the 4th line as the 2nd in `(void **)`?

Comment: CUDA is not C, but C++ based.

Comment: Allocate `(READS_LENGTH * inputDim)` bytes in a single chunk and you will never have to struggle with broken loops.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do cannot work because your code attempts to access memory you have allocated on the device from the host. You cannot access the elements of `gpu_reads`on the host because it is not a valid host memory allocation.

Do something like this instead:

```
   char ** gpu_reads;
   char ** gpu_reads_h = new char*[input_dim];
   HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_reads, inputDim * sizeof(char *)));
   for(i=0; i<inputDim; i++) {
      HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&(gpu_reads_h[i]), (READS_LENGTH + 1) * sizeof(char)));
   }
   for(i=0; i<inputDim; i++) {
      HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(gpu_reads_h[i], reads[i], sizeof(char) * (READS_LENGTH + 1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
   }

   HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(gpu_reads, gpu_reads_h, inputDim * sizeof(char *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

i.e. build a copy of the eventual device array of pointers in *host* memory first, then copy it to the device.

Comment: I tried this code, but I have the same "unknown error"...
I also tried to allocate with `(READS_LENGTH * inputDim)` like said @Drop but it doesn't work either

Comment: @Cordaz: If you are getting that error then you have another problem unrelated to the memory allocation and copying, like a non-functioning CUDA installation, or prior broken code which you haven't shown us. [Here](http://pastebin.com/VRy871fd) is a complete example from your code snippet which works perfectly for me. Try it for yourself

Comment: I tried your code and I get the same error... I installed CUDA 7.5 o Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried running it with `sudo`, and it returned this line:
`modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-uvm not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic`

I already tried to install this package, but after the reboot the system started in _low graphic mode_ and I had to restore previous Nvidia driver...

Comment: OK so you have a broken CUDA installation. [SO] isn't the correct place to get help with that, I am afraid.